# Windows Event ID Limitation

Tags: windows-7, event-log

We have a software that registers a specific ID as an Event ID and is added to the Windows event log. Here, the Event ID is incremented rather than using a specific Event ID and adding a body. This is something we cannot change. Therefore, is there any way to increase the Event ID limitation (65535)? Any programmatic way or through the registry? The client system is a Windows 7 x86. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Note: The question is not about the event log size but the Event ID limitation (I believe it is uint16 although it is told int32).

Thank you!

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>>https://helpcenter.netwrix.com/Configure_IT_Infrastructure/Windows_Server/WS_Event_Log_Settings.html

Comment: In non server OS highlight Windows Logs in left pane and then click properties in right pane.

Comment: @Moab thank you very much for your help. Actually I was looking more onto the event id limitation, not the log size :)

Comment: `the Event ID is incremented rather than using a specific Event ID` that's a bug. Don't do that. An Event ID is the actual event itself. Anything else is parameters. There's no body, there's a display template that's used to display those parameters. Many recent applications and log libraries though pass an entire string message as a parameter and use just a string specifier in the template.

Comment: I was able to reprogram using Visual Studio (It was in VB.Net) and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you're outa luck.  The data-type is hard-coded in the OS itself.  There indeed is only 16-bits available for the "event id".

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-identifiers

Without rebuilding the entire event system in Windows, and every application that reports to the event-manager, from source-code (not possible), you're out of luck.

I'm not sure what you're using to report events to the event-log... but it would be better to specify whatever incrementing ID you have as part of the message, instead of the "event id"... and using a static ID, or an ID that relates to the type of message (which is how it was intended).